# Android custom popup window get view location (inside the popup)

Tags: android, layout, popup, location, popupwindow

I'm trying to get the location of the View inside the popup but View.getX() method returns 0.0 
any help am trying to set the location of the removeAdsIm view to textCheck view

```
 public void showAdsOfferPopup(View v, Activity activity) {
    if (!getInAppBillingStatus()) {
        int width = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
        int height = display.getHeight();

        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        final View layout = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_ads_offer_new, null);
        .....
        textCheck = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupAdsOffer_checkTestIm);
        removeAdsIm = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupAdsOffer_removeAdsIm);
        playInBackgroundIm = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupAdsOffer_playInBackgroundIm);


        popup.setContentView(layout);
    ........

        popup.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        int test1[] = new int[2];
        removeAdsIm.getLocationOnScreen(test1);
        textCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        removeAdsIm.getX();
        removeAdsIm.getY();
        playInBackgroundIm.getX();
        playInBackgroundIm.getY();
        textCheck.setX(180);
        textCheck.setY(280);


    }
```